# Im getting this error in my file in my decorate.py file

Tags: django, django-views

[This is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADz54.png)

Although I tried to remove the httpresponse from my code even that isn't solving the issue.

```py
from multiprocessing import context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render


def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.authenticated:
           return redirect('homepage')
        else:
           return view_func(request,*args, **kwargs)
    
    return wrapper_func

def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request,*args, **kwargs):

           group is not None
           if request.user.groups.exists():  
              group=request.user.groups.all()[0].name
           if group in allowed_roles:
               return view_func(request,*args, **kwargs)
           if group == 'user':
            return render(request,'loginapp/user_dashboard')
           '''else:
               return HttpResponse('you are authorized')'''
               
        return  wrapper_func   
    return decorator
def admin_only(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request,*args, **kwargs):
        group is not None
        if request.user.groups.exists():  
              group=request.user.groups.all()[0].name
        if group == 'user':
            return render(request,'loginapp/user_dashboard')
        if group == 'admin':
              return render(request,'loginapp/admin_dashboard')
    return wrapper_func
```

..........................................................................

Comment: What view did you decorate?

Comment: what im trying to do is User Role Based Permissions & Authentication.

Comment: yes, but it seems like you used the decorator not to decorate, but as a view instead?

Comment: no i havent used it as a view.

Comment: well a decorator itself is not a view, you can not use a decorator in a `path`, or not directly. Otherwise it will pass the `request` object as `view_func`, and of course not return a HTTP response.